# How to update the values of yaml file using python code

Tags: python, json, dictionary, automation, yaml

I have task to update the values in the yaml file.
the yaml file is read into 'doc' with the yaml library with the below sysntax

```
    with open('createvol.yml') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)
```

print (doc) looks something like this.

```
[{'hosts': 'localhost', 'tasks': [{'register': 'result', 'test_lun': {'serial': 'P1234_K1', 'storageserial': '{{ storageserial }}', 'state': 'present', 'data': {'cap_compression': '{{ cap_compression | default(None) }}', 'storagepool': {'id': '{{ poolid | default(None) }}'}, 'name': '{{ name  | default(None) }}', 'vol': '{{ vol | default(None) }}', 'size': '{{ size | default(None) }}'}}}, {'debug': 'var=result'}], 'collections': ['company.storage'], 'name': 'Test Create vol', 'vars': [{'poolid': 200}, {'size': '7.3KB'}, {'storageserial': 111111}, {'name': 'test_vol_create'}, {'cap_compression': ['compression', 'deduplication']}], 'facts': False}]
```

Here i need to update the values under the 'vars' such as poolid, size, storageserial,name
may some one please help me with the python logic how to parse the doc content and update the values as required.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for sth quite similar. It appears that there's no way to update a single value in yaml files (wich is what I'd like to do) without having to parse the hole data into your code, transforming it as you will and then loading all the data back into the file.

But after having a look at the context of your question, it seams that parsing the hole data might be a usefull solution for you. So here it is:

First I'd recomend you **change your file extention** to `.yaml` instead of `.yml`. My previous researches pointed `.yml` as incompatible with some libraries, while `.yaml` does exactly the same but shouldn't give that kind of trouble in the future.

> *Note: you can import both `yaml` or `ruamel` libs. Once you're already using `yaml.load()`, here's how you can do it by only using
> `yaml`.

> *Note2: All the data is inside square brackets `[]`. In python, this represents a list with a single item (and I can see no reason for a list with a
> single item), this adds an unecessary layer of complexity to your
> code. I suggest you remove the fisrt `[` and the last `]`.

Despite Note2, the exemples I bring next are taking your 'single item list' into consideration. Let's have a look:

Your current `doc` variable is already loaded with `createvol.yml` file data.

So this:

```
print(doc[0]['hosts']) #[0] is only necessary because your data is inside square brackets []
```

Will return this:

```
localhost
```

Wich means you can run this:

```
# print first value of 'vars' (index = 0)
print("poolid is:")
print(doc[0]['vars'][0]['poolid']) #the first [0] is only necessary because your data is inside []

# change and print the second value of 'vars' (index = 1)
doc[0]['vars'][1]['size'] = '007 KB' #again: [0] is only necessary because your data is inside []

print("new size is:")
print(doc[0]['vars'][1]) #the first [0] is only necessary because your data is inside []
```

And get this:

```
poolid is:
200
new size is:
{'size': '007 KB'}
```

Using that idea you can update any value in your loaded data. Once you have it changed, you can open the file using `write` mode:

```
with open('createvol.yml', 'w') as f: #'w' stands for writing mode
        yaml.dump(doc, f)
```